I am trying to use the analysis tool- buffer to add a 100ft buffer to a streams layer
Initially, when I buffered the "streams" layer with the analysis/buffering tool I did so successfully.  I buffered the streams layer with a 100ft buffer and dissolved the feature into one feature class.  When I tried to buffer the stream layer again with a 100 meter buffer as per instructions for the project, I received a "PARAMETER IS MISSING OR INVALID" error message.  I did not change anything, but now I receive that error even if I start over and attempt again.  Any ideas?
I was trying to buffer the "streams" layer with two different linear measurements (feet and meters) as per course instructions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
